# Problems with NAudio

Tags: naudio

I am currently using NAudio to do the audio output. Everything is fine except there is an annoying echo in the background. What can I eliminate such noise?

Thanks, 
Adam

Comment: you'll need to provide more information than this. what are you trying to do with NAudio?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am doing a network chatting program with NAudio. NAudio in my project is used to process (play) the audio stream in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using a headset for a network chat program, then the received audio can get recorded by the microphone again, resulting in an annoying echo. There are some fairly complex echo suppression algorithms that programs like Skype use to detect and eliminate these echoes. Unfortunately NAudio does not include such an algorithm, so you'd need to find a third party one, or write your own.